# juju wordpress open-ports: []

Tags: juju, wordpress

testing juju from the ppa on aws on precise.

Environment successfully bootstrapped, mysql and wordpress unit started, db relationship successfully added. On exposure of wordpress I have no open ports (which IMO should be configured by the charm -- tried to upgrade charm, but already using latest wordpress-9 from the ppa).

open-ports: []

I would like to open the port, but why do I have to do it manually? And how can I do it?

I tried to use the open-port command, but it asks for a JUJU_CLIENT_ID and a JUJU_AGENT_SOCKET which I am not sure what they should point at.

I have read online other users don't need to open ports... it should work OOTB.

Juju status FYR:

```
machines:
  0:
    agent-state: running
    dns-name: xxx.amazonaws.com
    instance-id: yyy
    instance-state: running
services:
  mysql:
    charm: cs:precise/mysql-8
    relations:
      db:
      - wordpress
    units:
      mysql/0:
        agent-state: started
        machine: 0
        public-address: xxx.amazonaws.com
  wordpress:
    charm: cs:precise/wordpress-9
    exposed: true
    relations:
      db:
      - mysql
      loadbalancer:
      - wordpress
    units:
     wordpress/0:
        agent-state: started
        machine: 0
        open-ports: []
        public-address: xxx.amazonaws.com
```

Comment: Can you post the output from /var/lib/juju/units/wordpress-0/charm.log in to something like http://paste.ubuntu.com/ There's a chance that something went wrong during hook execution.

Comment: Darn... solved it. Basically it had nothing to do with Juju. The TCP port is not open by default in a newly spawned EC2 instance. Once added the ule in my security group on exposure of wordpress port 80/tcp is open. All is good now.

Comment: That's not how Juju works. When you run a `juju expose wordpress` Juju actually creates a security group and applies the port rules to that group. You may still be experiencing an issue or a bug with either Juju or the charm

Comment: @pberto, could you please update the community wiki answer below with the exact steps you took to resolve this issue? Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

@ppetraki

After I did a `juju expose wordpress` the charm was exposed (see my first post's juju status: `exposed: true`) BUT the port was NOT open. Hence I manually opened it by editing the instance security group allowing port 80. Note that my juju environment is set to have `placement: local`. I understand this is not a general solution, but it worked in my specific case.

@marcoceppi

I agree this is not a solution and I am pretty certain there is a bug somewhere in either juju or the charm. If I can help please let me know.